# Access Java variable from dynamic jsp

Tags: java, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

I have dynamically generated some checkboxes. Each checkbox is assigned a unique value which corresponds to an ArrayList position in my Java code. I have a `Singleton` object and I want to access that specific position of the ArrayList on click.

**How hard can this really be?**

I'm using `servlets` and `.jsp`

so, let's say the checkboxes are generated like so:

```
select.jsp
<html>
<head>
    <script src="text/javascript">
        function select(i) {
            Model.getInstance().getArrayList().get(i).select();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <%for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){%>
         <div class="checkbox" id="<%=cluster_id%>">
            <label><input type="checkbox" value="<%=i%>"onclick="select('<%=i%>')"></label>
        </div>
    <%}%>
</body>
</html>
```

This is such a simple concept, but why is so hard to implement?

Any help?

Answer (score -1):

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="<%=i%>"onclick="select('<%=i%>')">
</label>
```

Comment: i found many things online and cant get it to work. can you provide some code?

Comment: <label><input type="checkbox" id="<%=i%>"onclick="select('<%=i%>')"></label>

Comment: isn't this what I have done in the code above? 
I'm asking how to use this information to change a variable in my Java code.

Comment: In your code you made value="<%=i%>". I asked you to make id="<%=i%> so that you can access the id value in select function return in javascript